# Is multiplication of a correlated random variable and a independent random variable, an independent random variable

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I have a random variable that is a multiplication of two random variables as bellow:
$$A_n=B_n\times C_n$$
$B_n$s are identically distributed with  zero mean and are correlated for different $n$s and $C_n$s are independent and identically distributed with  zero mean. My question is that are $A_n$s independent? By the way $B_n$ and $C_n$ are independent.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not independent.

For a simple example, imagine that the $B_n$ alternate between huge absolute values (odd $n$) and small (even $n$); and all the $C_n$ either $\pm 1,$ with coin tosses. Then the $A_n$ will alternate huge and small absolute values in step with the $B_n$.

It would surely be convenient if one could get rid of serial
correlation in a sequence of random variables as simply as multiplying by a sequence of independent random variables.

Comment: Thanks. How about the case where $B_n$ is Gaussian and $C_n$ is bernoulli (+1 or -1)?

Comment: Don't think that would give independence. What kind of serial correlation do you have in mind for $B_n$? Certainly, alternating large and small standard deviations would not be mitigated. We can chase proposals forever, but I don't see how you can prove independence for any.

Comment: I want to use the central limit theorem for $\sum_n A_n$. I can prove that $A_n$s are uncorrelated but I can't prove that they are independent. I have plotted the histogram of $\sum_n A_n$ and it is Gaussian but I can't use the central limit theorem since  I can't prove that $A_n$s are independent. Does the central limit theorem hold for uncorrelated random variables?

Comment: Not in general, but in certain cases. There are many forms of the CLT. And if $A_n$ is an ergodic Markov sequence. then it has a limit that may or may not be normal. Now that we're down to the $real$ problem, maybe you can make a new post explaining what you're trying to do, and see if someone can help with that. Be sure to reveal the nature/source of the autocorrelation. Another question: does it help at all to take logs and deal with sums instead of products?

Comment: One issue is whether you are solving a particular practical problem or looking for a general mathematical solution. For example, you say the $A_n$ are uncorrelated (presumably you looked at an ACF plot). In practice it's possible but relatively rare to find zero correlation (autocorrelation) without indep. If you are looking for a general math solution, you will need to find a way to model dependence. In simulation work such as MCMC, one routinely looks at ACF plots. If ACF decays to insignif corr beyond a certain lag (say 10), then one 'thins' to use every tenth obs.& assumes they're indep.